# Inner form submit using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am using asp.net Master -content page. MasterPage already has root level `<form>` tag.
My content page contact has another `<form>` tag area for validation purpose.

When I submit form root level `<form>` executing instead of validation `<form>` tag.

### MasterPage

```
   <form runat="server">
```

### Contactus.aspx

```
 <form id="validForm">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputName">NAME<sup>*</sup></label>
          <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="span4" id="inputName" placeholder="Name"/>
          <span class="help-inline">Please fill your name</span>
          </div>
    </div>                                         
    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">EMAIL<sup>*</sup></label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span4" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
            <span class="help-inline">Please correct your email</span>
          </div>
     </div>                                        
     <div class="control-group">
        <label for="textarea" class="control-label">COMMENT<sup>*</sup></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea rows="4" class="span8" id="textarea" runat="server" ></textarea>
            <span class="help-inline">Please write a comment</span>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="control-group form-button-offset">
           <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Message" />
           <%--   <asp:Button class="btn" Text="Send Message" runat="server" id="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />--%>
    </div>
</form>                                
                                </div>
```

### Mail_Validation.Js

```
var $mjq = jQuery.noConflict();
$mjq(function(){
    $mjq(document).ready(function(){
         $mjq(".help-inline").each(function() {
            $mjq(this).css('display', 'none');
         });
    });
    $mjq("#inputEmail").bind('blur', is_valid_email);
    $mjq("#inputName").bind('blur', is_valid_name);
    $mjq("#textarea").bind('blur', is_valid_comment);
    $mjq('#validForm').bind('submit', function() {
        return is_valid_form();
    });
});
```

I have called exclusively `is_valid_form();` on button click, still parent form overriding this.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
         $('.btn').click(function () {
             //$(this).closest('validForm')[0].submit();
             return is_valid_form();
         });
```

Now how to validate my form here.

Comment: I'm no ASP expert, but I can say with certainty that you cannot nest a `<form></form>` inside of a `<form></form>`.  I know there are workarounds for this situation, I just don't know where to point you.

Comment: And your code indicates you are not using the jQuery Validate plugin so I've removed the [tag:jquery-validate] tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple forms on one page but you should not nest them according to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element).

Comment: more specifically browser will simply drop one of the forms